# How can I reset jQuery sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I **reset** the sorting by using jQuery?

The ASC and DESC sorting works perfectly, but I found no way, where I can reset the sorting back to default list with button click:

- Jack
- Evelyn
- Jackson
- Mason
- James
- William

Here the code snippet where the sorting works for ASC and DESC:

```js
$('#sortByNameASC').click(function (){
  $('.list .col').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).find(".name").text() > $(b).find(".name").text() ? 1 : -1;
  }).appendTo(".list");
})

$('#sortByNameDESC').click(function (){
  $('.list .col').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).find(".name").text() < $(b).find(".name").text() ? 1 : -1;
  }).appendTo(".list");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="sortByNameASC">Sort ASC</button>
<button id="sortByNameDESC">Sort DESC</button>
<button id="resetSorting">Reset</button>

<div class="list py-2">
  <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">Jack</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">Evelyn</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">Jackson</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">Mason</li>
  </div>
    <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">James</li>
  </div>
    <div class="col">
      <li class="search-filter name">William</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have try with cache the default list, but this doesn't work. Any ideas how I can achieve this

Comment: You would need to store the original sorting somewhere.  My suggestion would be to store the `index()` of each item against that item, eg in a data- or `$(this).data("original-index", index)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should note that your HTML is invalid. `li` elements cannot be children of a `div`, only `ul` or `ol`. That needs to be corrected in your HTML and current sorting logic.

With regard to your goal of 'resetting' to the original order, you can loop through the elements and store their initial index in the element metadata when the page loads. Then you can use the same pattern you currently have to sort by the original index when the 'reset' button is clicked.

Try this:

```js
let $items = $('.list .col .name');

// store original index order on load:
$items.each((i, el) => $(el).data('index', i));

// restore original order:
$('#resetSorting').on('click', () => {
  $items.sort((a, b) => $(a).data('index') > $(b).data('index') ? 1 : -1).appendTo('.col');
});

$('#sortByNameASC').on('click', () => {
  $items.sort((a, b) => $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1).appendTo(".col");
});

$('#sortByNameDESC').on('click', () => {
  $items.sort((a, b) => $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? 1 : -1).appendTo(".col");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="sortByNameASC">Sort ASC</button>
<button id="sortByNameDESC">Sort DESC</button>
<button id="resetSorting">Reset</button>

<div class="list py-2">
  <ul class="col">
    <li class="search-filter name">Jack</li>
    <li class="search-filter name">Evelyn</li>
    <li class="search-filter name">Jackson</li>
    <li class="search-filter name">Mason</li>
    <li class="search-filter name">James</li>
    <li class="search-filter name">William</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```